# Extend AspNetCore View Discovery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm looking for a way to extend the AspNetCore MVC view discovery logic. I want to be able to inherit from a controller and have the new controller have access to the Actions of the base Controller. Is there a way to extend the view discovery logic so that you can tell a controller where to look for its vies, to look in the folder of the controller, look in a folder based on the name of the base controller, or even look in a folder based on the namespace of the controller?

~/Controllers/UserAccountController.cs

```
namespace App.Controllers.UserAccount 
{
    public class UserAccountController {
       public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Action1()
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
}
```

~/Controllers/UserAccountExtController.cs

```
namespace App.Controllers.UserAccount 
{
    public class UserAccountExtController : UserAccountController {
       public override async Task<IActionResult> Action1()
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can extend the view discovery logic so that it if it does not find the view in the view folder with the same name as the Controller name, that it will look in the folder based on an Attribute of the controller, or the folder of the inherited controller, the folder that the controller exists in, or a folder based on the namespace of the controller?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to achieve and why other than "get a view from another folder". Why not use the [View(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_View_System_String_) overload?

Comment: Since asp.net and .net core uses conventions over configuration, therefore for `ABCController` it expects an **ABC** folder in the Views folder, and for action named `MyAction` it expects **MyAction.cshtml** file unless another name is specified explicitly in `View("ViewFileName")`. 
Now to change these conventions, you have to define Custom View Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a IViewLocationExpander to solve the issue thanks to [RandyBuchholz](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156415/Custom-View-Paths-and-View-Hierarchies-in-MVC-Core) for the tip on casting the ActionContext to a ControllerActionContext, which allowed me to identify the BaseType of the controller. This allowed be to add the convention of checking the default location of the BaseController if a view didn't exist in the default location for the Controller.

```
public class MyViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        // list used for future extension
        var alternateLocations = new List<string>();

        if (context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            var baseType = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.BaseType.Name;
            if (!baseType.StartsWith("Controller"))
            {
                var baseLocation = baseType.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
                alternateLocations.Add("/Views/" + baseLocation + "/{0}.cshtml");
            }
        }

        var locations = viewLocations.ToList();
        locations.InsertRange(locations.IndexOf("/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml") - 1, alternateLocations);

        return locations;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Then just register the IViewLocationExpander in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
            {
                var expander = new MyViewLocationExpander();
                options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(expander);
            });
       //...
    }
```